# Problem with 0x Protocol Goerli API

Tags: 0x

I'm trying to test the 0x quote API, ran into an issue with the Goerli endpoint.

I sent a quote request to mainnet, to sell WETH and buy USDC:
https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=USDC&sellToken=WETH&sellAmount=100000000000000000

There is no issue, I received the correct response:

```
{"chainId":1,"price":"1323.97485","guaranteedPrice":"1310.7351","estimatedPriceImpact":"0","to":"0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff","data":"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","value":"0","gas":"125195","estimatedGas":"125195","gasPrice":"18500000000","protocolFee":"0","minimumProtocolFee":"0","buyTokenAddress":"0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48","sellTokenAddress":"0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2","buyAmount":"132397485","sellAmount":"100000000000000000","sources":[{"name":"0x","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Uniswap","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Uniswap_V2","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Curve","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Balancer","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Balancer_V2","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Bancor","proportion":"0"},{"name":"BancorV3","proportion":"0"},{"name":"mStable","proportion":"0"},{"name":"SushiSwap","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Shell","proportion":"0"},{"name":"DODO","proportion":"0"},{"name":"DODO_V2","proportion":"0"},{"name":"CryptoCom","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Lido","proportion":"0"},{"name":"MakerPsm","proportion":"0"},{"name":"KyberDMM","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Component","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Saddle","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Uniswap_V3","proportion":"1"},{"name":"Curve_V2","proportion":"0"},{"name":"ShibaSwap","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Synapse","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Synthetix","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Aave_V2","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Compound","proportion":"0"}],"orders":[{"type":0,"source":"Uniswap_V3","makerToken":"0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48","takerToken":"0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2","makerAmount":"132397485","takerAmount":"100000000000000000","fillData":{"router":"0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564","tokenAddressPath":["0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2","0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48"],"uniswapPath":"0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20001f4a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48","gasUsed":65195},"fill":{"input":"100000000000000000","output":"132397485","adjustedOutput":"129967849","gas":99195}}],"allowanceTarget":"0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff","decodedUniqueId":"7ec526fe6c-1673274722","sellTokenToEthRate":"1","buyTokenToEthRate":"1323.97485","expectedSlippage":"-0.001112727338236046"}
```

I then sent the exact same request to the Goerli endpoint:
https://goerli.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=USDC&sellToken=WETH&sellAmount=100000000000000000

It returned me the following error message:

```
{'code': 100, 'reason': 'Validation Failed', 'validationErrors': [{'field': 'buyToken', 'code': 1000, 'reason': 'buyToken and sellToken must be different'}, {'field': 'sellToken', 'code': 1000, 'reason': 'buyToken and sellToken must be different'}]}
```

Any idea what caused the issue here? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Jan 10, 2023, there is no token symbol support on Goerli, and limited token symbol support on Mainnet. The request works on Mainnet but fails on Goerli for this reason

For Goerli, you will need to use token addresses instead of token symbols. For example:

```
https://goerli.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f&sellToken=0xb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6&sellAmount=100000000000000000
```

- Goerli USDC https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f
- Goerli WETH https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6

Comment: It works now, thanks!